# Which model field type would be appropriate for a date-time object that is repeatedly saved in the database, and needs to be displayed as a string?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

The question is a bit ambiguous, allow me to explain:

I'm creating something like a changelog, which will note the date-time an object is created along with the objects created. When the objects are updated in the database, I'll get a snapshot of the date-time and record the newly changed objects along with the current & new date-time--the previous snapshots of object+date-time are already also stored. Here is an example of the kind of "changelog" I am trying to display as text on the site:

```
Oct. 24, 2017, 11:22 a.m  
"Cats and dogs", "Apples and oranges"  

Oct. 19, 2017, 12:04 p.m  
"This is a string object", "This is the second object/preference"  

Sep. 03, 2017, 01:22 a.m   
"This object was saved long ago", "As was this one"
```

*So, the question is two-fold*--which model fieldtypes would be appropriate for an object that needs to record the current date-time, but also how do I have the previous changelogs **persist in the DB** as text to be displayed, instead of just querying the most recent one?

**In the following failed attempt**, the `Profile` model contains the objects/"preferences" to be changed and recorded, and an `updated` field to save the current date-time when the object is saved. The plan was to send a signal post-save of the object that would call the `get_preference()` classmethod that returns a tuple of the objects to be recorded. This would be saved onto the `old_preferences` attribute via the post_save signal which would be queried in the View and sent to the template as part of the changelog.

Based on my understanding, when I update the form, it should cause a `save()` which would trigger the signal.
Alas, it simply does not work, and I don't know enough to know why it doesn't.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    preference1 = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True)
    preference2 = models.CharField(max_length=54, blank=True, null=True)  
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    old_preferences = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    @classmethod
    def get_preference(cls):
        preference_set = cls.preference1, cls.preference2
        return preference_set


def profile_post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance:
        Profile.objects.old_preferences = Profile.get_preference()

post_save.connect(profile_post_save_receiver, sender=Profile)
```

Additionally, here are the related parts to the View, Form, and Template

view:

```
class PreferenceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = PreferenceUpdateForm
    template_name = 'profile/preference_edit.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # print(self.kwargs)
        user_profile = self.kwargs.get('username')
        # user_profile = self.kwargs.get('id')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user_profile)
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(self.kwargs)
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(PreferenceUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

template:

```
{{object.updated}}
{{object.old_preferences}}
```

form:

```
from .models import Profile
from django import forms

class PreferenceUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "preference1",
            "preference2",
        ]
```

edit: Please let me know if I need to clarify the question further

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, but this looks like a pretty complicated approach. Why don't you just keep the old profiles as data sets in Profile? You would only have to change the relation to ManyToOne and in your UpdateView make sure you only read the most recent Profile:

model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True)


from django.http import Http404
```

view

```
class PreferenceUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = PreferenceUpdateForm
    template_name = 'profile/preference_edit.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = self.kwargs.get('username')
        try:
            obj = Profile.objects.filter(user__username=user_profile).latest('updated')
            return obj
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

Comment: What do you mean by keeping the old preferences "as datasets"? What format would I save them in the DB in order to retrieve all previous logs corresponding to a single user? Might this be a case for a whole new model?

Comment: I mean instead of just keeping one Profile and updating it, create a new Profile every time the user changes the preferences and only read the latest one using `latest()`